# CSS dropdown menu: position of subitems

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I try to create a dropdown menu with CSS for a Wordpress template. When I hover a menuitem (e.g. "Cupcake Ipsum" like you can see on the picture), the whole menu is displayed in a weird way.

I hope the picture is self-explanatory enough. The menuitem "Cupcake Ipsum" is hovered on the bottom view of the menu:

[image]

My HTML code (from firebug) is:

```
<div id="menu" role="navigation">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">
<a title="Home" href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-40">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=40">Cupcake Ipsum</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-388">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=388">Red Velvet Cupcake</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-390">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=390">Mango Cupcake</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-392">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=392">Chocolate Cupcake</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-43">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=43">Bacon Ipsum</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-405">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-45">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=45">Veggie Ipsum</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-397">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=397">Tomato</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-399">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=399">Lettuce</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-401">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=401">Broccoli</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-403">
<a href="http://whatever.com/wordpress/?page_id=403">Onion</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
#menu ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #CCCCCC;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px;
display: block;
position:relative;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
background-color: #006699;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
clear: left;
line-break: strict;
background-color: #006699;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 10px;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
clear: left;
}

.menu ul li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.menu li ul {
position: absolute;
}

.menu li:not(:hover) ul {
display: none; 
}
```

I want to create a dropdown menu where one subitem is below the other. Tried a lot but I cannot manage to arrange the subitems correcly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you omit? Your exact code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj9X4/) works, check your css, you have something overriding some of your rules, check each element, see when the rules you pasted here are overwritten.

Comment: aah thank you! had that stupid mistake and overwrote the .menu li ul {
position: absolute;
}
will doublecheck it next time!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your code in a jsfiddle? Until then, I can tell you that one of your sub elements of the main `<li>` is `display: block;` and pushing the other top level `<li>`'s out of placement.